# Python excel append data

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, openpyxl

I am trying to append stemmed words into the rows in column L in excel, however I want it to append the values one by one in the for loop for each cell and then move on to the next, if I do ws[L1]= stemmeddata, it will only input the last word into the cell.

```
from hashlib import new
import pandas as pd
from string import punctuation
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer


pst=PorterStemmer()
wb = load_workbook('report.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
sbst=SnowballStemmer('english')
df = pd.read_excel('report.xlsx')

for row in range(2,10):
    for col in range(10,11):
        char = get_column_letter(col)
        data = ws[char + str(row)].value
        data = data.lower()
        data = data.replace('-',"").replace('"',"").replace(':',"").replace('/',"").replace(',',"")
        new = word_tokenize(data)
        
        for w in new:
            stemmeddata = pst.stem(w)
            #print(stemmeddata)
    for i in range(2,20):
        ws['L'+ str(i)] = stemmeddata

wb.save('stem.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#  other codes
df = pd.read_excel('report.xlsx')

stemmeddata = "" #  Add this
for row in range(2,10):
    #  other codes
        
        for w in new:
            stemmeddata += pst.stem(w) #  Add plus sign, instead of just = sign
    #  other codes
```

You need to initialize stemmeddata (better variable name is stemmed_data) and concatenate new data inside the loop. Alternative concatenation is:

```
stemmeddata = stemmeddata + pst.stem(w)
```

Without initializing, stemmeddata gets the last data you've assigned to it.

Comment: I tried the code below but it just prints the output as 'havehave', am I doing it wrong?

`
        for w in new:
            stemmed_data = pst.stem(w)
            stemmed_data = stemmed_data + pst.stem(w)
            print(stemmed_data)
`

Using
```
stemmed_data = stemmed_data += pst.stem(w)
`
Didnt work as stemmed_data was not defined

Comment: Write the line as shown 'stemmeddata += pst.stem(w)' not 'stemmed_data = stemmed_data += pst.stem(w)'